# Let $f \in Hol(B_{1+ϵ}(0))$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and $f(C_1(0)) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is a constant function.

Tags: complex-analysis

$B_{r}(0)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $0$, and $C_r(0)$ is its boundary,.

Let $f \in Hol(B_{1+\epsilon}(0))$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and $f(C_1(0)) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is a constant function.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Hint: This means the imaginary part of $f$ is $0$ on the boundary

Comment: So I use the open-mapping theorem to say that the image of the open disc should be open if it is non-constant, and that the the image of boundary must be atleast the boundary of the open set, as the image of the closed disc is compact.  I'm done, right?